# How TMS behaves when a component is sent for Translation in more than 1 translation jobs for the same target language?

Tags: translation-manager, 2013-sp1-hr1

I have a scenario where users have created different component bundles and sending these bundles for translation (say German) through TMS.
Now few bundles contain same component i.e. 1 component present in more than 1 bundle:

Q.1. As per my understanding the TMS will only pick the component from 1 bundle and ignore others, which means Worldserver is going to receive only 1 instance of that component hence cost wise users will be charged for 1 component only?

Q.2. Is there any side effect or consequences of having same component in different bundle/jobs sent for translation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, TMS and WorldServer are two completely separate translation system, which one are you using?

To answer your question:

1) WorldServer is going to receive whatever job you send them. If you send two jobs, there's going to be two there.

2) If you have two packages sent to translation the 1st job will just be overwritten by the 2nd job once it is complete

Comment: Thanks @Robert Jin, I agree that TMS & Worldserver are 2 different things, however, I don't think that the same component if it is already locked by MTSUser in a target language can be sent twice to the WorldServer even if sent in a different job. I just tried something similar and got the error message "Error Sending" cannot find any translatable field. I think this use case can be added in the SDL Doc with other troubleshooting examples.

Comment: Hi Yash, you could send the same component to translation, it's not a problem. One source could go to multiple target destinations. The issue you are getting is different issue. Make sure all schema AND embeddable schema have fields that are translatable. Also, make sure  "Include already translated items" is checked

Comment: Hi @Robert, Yes I agree with you that 1 source component can be sent to multiple target destinations, but I am talking about same target language i.e. 1 target destination.

Comment: yes, thats possible too. There's no control what you sent over. Whichever workflow complete last will have that updated version

Answer (score -1):

> For Q1.

If both the bundles are added to the same TMS job, then the duplicate component in the 2nd component will be filtered by TMS before it reaches Worldserver, if it is a different job, both components will reach TMS

Cost: **The tranlsation cost stays same** whether you send the component to WS 1 time or multiple times as the WS translation memory gets updated when the 1st component  is translated and approved in WS. If you opt for human review, then a fraction of Translation cost is going to get added for each duplication component.

> For Q2

Consequences, if the same component is available in 2 jobs and both are sent for translation simultaneously, sometimes I have noticed that one of the TMS job endsup in "Error Retrieving" state, because translation has completed successfully and came back from WS to SDL Web, but TMS was not able to update already locked component by another TMS Job and so unable complete the transaction successfully, hence ends up in error state.

So, its better to send such jobs with duplicate components in a sequential manner to overcome this lock issue.

Hope this information helps